# How can I extract the value of my current local time offset?

Tags: go, timezone-offset

I'm struggling a bit trying to format and display some IBM mainframe TOD clock data. I want to format the data in both GMT and local time (as the default -- otherwise in the zone the user specifies).

For this, I need to get the value of the local time offset from GMT as a signed integer number of seconds.

In zoneinfo.go (which I confess I don't fully understand), I can see

```
// A zone represents a single time zone such as CEST or CET.
type zone struct {
    name   string // abbreviated name, "CET"
    offset int    // seconds east of UTC
    isDST  bool   // is this zone Daylight Savings Time?
}
```

but this is not, I think, exported, so this code doesn't work:

```
package main
import ( "time"; "fmt" )

func main() {
    l, _ := time.LoadLocation("Local")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", l.zone.offset)
}
```

Is there a simple way to get this information?

Comment: @olif wins, in a very close-run thing. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the Zone() method on the time type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    zone, offset := t.Zone()
    fmt.Println(zone, offset)
}
```

*Zone computes the time zone in effect at time t, returning the abbreviated name of the zone (such as "CET") and its offset in seconds east of UTC.*

Comment: This has the args wrong - Should be z, _ := t.Zone(), assuming you want the timezone as a string.

Answer (score 11):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> [func (Time) Local](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Local)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) Local() Time
> ```
>
> Local returns t with the location set to local time.
>
> [func (Time) Zone](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Zone)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) Zone() (name string, offset int)
> ```
>
> Zone computes the time zone in effect at time t, returning the
>   abbreviated name of the zone (such as "CET") and its offset in seconds
>   east of UTC.
>
> [type Location](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location)
>
> ```
> type Location struct {
>         // contains filtered or unexported fields
> }
> ```
>
> A Location maps time instants to the zone in use at that time.
>   Typically, the Location represents the collection of time offsets in
>   use in a geographical area, such as CEST and CET for central Europe.
>
> ```
> var Local *Location = &localLoc
> ```
>
> Local represents the system's local time zone.
>
> ```
> var UTC *Location = &utcLoc
> ```
>
> UTC represents Universal Coordinated Time (UTC).
>
> [func (Time) In](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) In(loc *Location) Time
> ```
>
> In returns t with the location information set to loc.
>
> In panics if loc is nil.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()

    // For a time t, offset in seconds east of UTC (GMT)
    _, offset := t.Local().Zone()
    fmt.Println(offset)

    // For a time t, format and display as UTC (GMT) and local times.
    fmt.Println(t.In(time.UTC))
    fmt.Println(t.In(time.Local))
}
```

Output:

```
-18000
2016-01-24 16:48:32.852638798 +0000 UTC
2016-01-24 11:48:32.852638798 -0500 EST
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it makes sense to manually convert time to another TZ. Use [time.Time.In](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In) function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func printTime(t time.Time) {
    zone, offset := t.Zone()
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.Kitchen), "Zone:", zone, "Offset UTC:", offset)
}

func main() {
    printTime(time.Now())
    printTime(time.Now().UTC())

    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
    printTime(time.Now().In(loc))
}
```