# TimeZone to Offset?

Tags: go, timezone

I want to get the offset in seconds from a specified time zone. That is exactly what `tz_offset()` in Perl's [Time::Zone](https://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Time/Zone.pm) does: "determines the offset from GMT in seconds of a specified timezone".

Is there already a way of doing this in Go? The input is a string that has the time zone name *and that's it*, but I know that Go has `LoadLocation()` in the `time` package, so *string => offset* or *location => offset* should be fine.

**Input:** "MST"

**Output:** -25200

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975007/in-go-how-can-i-extract-the-value-of-my-current-local-time-offset

Comment: This is not the same question by any means. I edited my question to make it clearer, though.

Comment: @OmarOthman You can't get offset by string because offset depends on time as well. Think about [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), or the fact that [time zones change](http://play.golang.org/p/6BHVVE9aIT).

Comment: @Ainar-G Thank you for your comment, I am a beginner in that world. But take a look [here](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/HTTP-Date-6.02/lib/HTTP/Date.pm#L71), this is exactly what is happening!

Comment: @OmarOthman hm, [time.Time.Zone](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Zone) function returns offset of the current zone from UTC (GMT basically). `loc, err := time.LoadLocation("MST"); _, offset := Time.Now().In(loc).Zone()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
location, err := time.LoadLocation("MST")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

tzName, tzOffset := time.Now().In(location).Zone()

fmt.Printf("name: [%v]\toffset: [%v]\n", tzName, tzOffset)
```

Will print:

> name: [MST]    offset: [-25200]

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/GVTgnpe1mB1

Comment: Be careful with the short timezone identifiers. I wanted Eastern Time, so I put EST, but that gave me Eastern Standard Time when it's currently Eastern Daylight Time in New York. I had to put "America/New_York" to get the _current_ timezone, rather than an exact daylight-savings-shifted timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, that calculates current offset between local and specified timezones. I agree with [Ainar-G's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036951/timezone-to-offset?noredirect=1#comment57799919_35036951) that offset makes sense only with relation to specified moment in time:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("MST")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    now := time.Now()
    _, destOffset := now.In(loc).Zone()
    _, localOffset := now.Zone()

    fmt.Println("Offset:", destOffset-localOffset)
}
```

Comment: I don't want the offset from the local time zone, I want it from GMT. Does that change anything? Could you please change your code to reflect this?

Comment: Also, could you please take a look at my last comment on the question itself?